# Can I use multiple animations in 1 view ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I am trying to create an aquarium style app where the fish and bubbles move once the app is opened using swift and xcode 6.2. The code I am using only allows me to use it once. If I try to use it more the once the animations dont work correctly, they become jumpy and if I try it 3 or more times the animations disappear completely from the app. Does anybody know what code I could use to achieve what I am after or how to alter the code I already have to achieve this. The app is a single view with up to 8 animations. Here is the code I have been using with the (func performBubbles1) and (imgBubbles1) being changed accordingly to match what image view is going to be animated and with what animation.

```
timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2, target: self, selector: Selector("performBubbles1"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
    
    func performBubbles1() {
        counter++
        
        if (counter==15) {
            counter = 1
            
        }
        imgBubbles1.image = UIImage(named: "bubbles\(counter).png")
```

I am new to coding so apologise if this makes no sense or if this has been answered. I have not been able to find the answer I am after.
Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

The approach you're using was not designed to be used that way. You don't want to use `NSTimer` to essentially act as a render loop. It isn't accurate enough. Additionally, UIKit isn't really designed to swap images like you are at a high frame rate for a variety of different reasons.

What you're actually looking for is [SpriteKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Introduction/Introduction.html). It is designed for making games, but will fit your use case very VERY well. Here is a great `SpriteKit` tutorial to get you started.

- [Sprite Kit Swift Tutorial for Beginners](http://www.raywenderlich.com/84434/sprite-kit-swift-tutorial-beginners)

Comment: Cnoon. Thankyou. I have had a look and am going to give it go. Appreciate the help